# Rails 2.3.5 with rails_xss escaping content_for yielded content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, erubis

Just upgraded Rails to 2.3.5 to get the lovely looking [rails_xss plugin](http://github.com/NZKoz/rails_xss) but I've noticed one big issue with it. Any `content_for` blocks are escaped when yielded.

I've tried hacking it around by doing the either of following but they do not work:

```
<% @content_for_foo.html_safe! -%>
<%= yield raw :foo %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<%= raw yield :foo %>`

Comment: You sir, are my hero! I couldn't figure out why none of the content_for stuff was working for me!